# Differential forms on the circle

Tags: differential-forms

Firstly, I apologies for the very stupid question.

I was trying to learn about differential forms on the circle, and I've come across this:

> The circle is parametrized by the angle $\theta$. A differential 1-form on the circle is of the form $g d\theta$, where $g$ is smooth function on the circle.

I don't understand what is $d\theta$, it is the exterior derivative of which function ?

Comment: $d\theta$ is dual basis of $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$

Comment: These [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3405035/explanation-of-this-proof-of-d-theta-not-being-an-exact-form), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6083/how-do-you-show-that-d-theta-fracx-dy-y-dx-x2-y2) might give you some idea.

Comment: Dear psl2Z and Arctic Char , your comments where of great help, Thank you very much:)